# AR representation of an MA(3) process

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics

I'm currently learning about Backshift operators, AR process, MA process, and invertibility and I would like to know how you can represent an MA(3) process as a AR process.

Comment: It would have infinite order.

Comment: Okay, got it. What does that look like/what does that mean? and how do we get there?